# Called while not using phone, after call, screen stays on, how to fix?

Tags: phone-app

I can understand it staying on for other apps, but after ending a call someone else initiated it should make an exception. Is there a setting to change the default phone app behavior for these cases?

Comment: Doesn't it go to sleep quickly, though? I see it staying on for a really short time, it gives you a chance to glance at a few things like how long the conversation was.

Comment: Does it stay longer than your screen light time out?

Comment: I believe it stays on the same time as the other apps (screen light time out, which I usually set at 2 minutes.) The thing is you'd think there would be an exception when the screen turns on just because someone called you when you weren't using the phone before and after the call, like when you get a call but don't answer it, the screen times out much quicker in those cases.